# mySql Inner/left Join from Variable tables

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, inner-join

I have a table called `activities`, inside that table i have these useful columns (not mentioning all the columns)

```
`item_id` AND `table`
```

And few different tables, now basically what this `activities` table does is to point to the targets inside different tables, say

```
SELECT * FROM `activities` WHERE `user_id` = 1;
```

You get :

```
ID:1    TABLE:photos    ITEM_ID:55
ID:2    TABLE:posts     ITEM_ID:57
```

and so on...

I want to get the data from the value of the `table` column, here I have one `photos` one `posts` these are different tables.

I could do this using PHP loop:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `activities` WHERE `user_id` = 1;'

$results = $DB->GetRows($query);
foreach($results as $result){
    $table = $result->table;
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM `$table` WHERE `user_id` = '1'";
    $res = $DB->GetRows($query2);

}
```

So here I can get the results form the other tables, but I want a query instead of multiple queries, if that’s possible.

Comment: What are you having eliminate what when they match up?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UNION` keyword in order to merge the results of two results into one, but this is only possible if they share the same structure.

Also, It is risky business to SELECT from a variable that contains your table name, I would strongly suggest you to change it for security purposes.

Comment: now i'm using this:
$query = "  (SELECT `identifier`, `date_created` as dt from `photos` WHERE `uid` = '$uid')
                    UNION
                   (SELECT `identifier`, `date_created` as dt from `posts` WHERE `uid` = '$uid')
                    ORDER BY dt DESC LIMIT $tpage,$limit ";

Answer (score 0):

You can get results in several resultsets:

```
SELECT  photos.*
FROM    activities
JOIN    photos
ON      photos.id = activities.item_id
WHERE   activities.table = 'photos'

SELECT  posts.*
FROM    activities
JOIN    posts
ON      posts.id = activities.item_id
WHERE   activities.table = 'posts'
```

Most probably, table setups for `photos` and `posts` are different, so you can't get them in a single resultset.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with standard SQL. Consider this:

```
create table foo (bar text);
insert into foo ('baz');
select * from (select bar from foo)
```

There is absolutely **NO** way for you to tell the DB that you actually want it to use the `baz` value you've stored in the `foo` table as the name of a table to do its `select *` on. Instead, you'll actually get:

```
ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias
```

because that `select bar` query's results are going to be used a temporary table, and you'll fetch all of  that temp table's records instead, ending up with a result set of `baz`, instead of fetching from a table named `baz`.

You need to use a stored procedure, dynamically built your query, and `exec()` it within the database.